# Variable life time in java script

Tags: javascript

Assume that, I have following a codes in document.ready event

```
$(function(){
      var a=1;
      $("#btn").on("click",function(){
          a++;
          var b=1;
          function foo(){
               alert(a*b);
               b++;
          }
     }
 }
```

In this case, what is the life time of variable 'a' and 'b'. Is new 'b' allocated in every call of click event and previous b deleted by garbage collector?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: The lifetime of `a` is the same as of the `click`  callback and depends on how long it is attached to the DOMElement. About `b`  if there would have been a Object assigned then yes the Object assigned to `b` would be gc if it was not referenced anywhere anymore (not the variabel is  gc but the object that was assigned to it)

Comment: If you would be using `let` instead of `var` it should be a new b every time.

Comment: @Cludch no in this particular example there would not be a difference in using `let` and `var`

Comment: Oh, yeah you're right. But when using `var` it would be still the same variable, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Cludch no look at this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/xfuya56e/1/) both `res1();` and `res1();` will do `console.log(b);` but both `b` are different variables. `res1` will log `value1` and `res2` will log `value2`.

Comment: @overlord  `b` will already be gone at the end of the execution of the callback function and not at the the next click..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have one more question: What about 'foo' function? Can we same things like b. Is it allocated in every button click?I am very new at java script and I haven't experience like this situation in other language that I use.